# GPU isn't turning on

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

so, i have a prebuilt that i've been upgrading (don't worry, it's only temporary) and the GPU stopped turning on when i turn on the computer, im using it now by plugging the DVI cable into my mobo.

i have an Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 ti

an EVGA 750 watt gold power supply

two hard drives (1tb and 2tb respectively)

and a 6 core AMD CPU (not sure what the specifications are)

my computer runs fine but i can't get the resolution above 1280 x 1024 (before it was 1920 x 1080) so i can't play any of my games now, i've tried getting a new DVI cable, i've checked and the GPU is visually sound (i.e. no obvious signs of overheating or damage), the power supply works with everything else in my computer just fine so i doubt it's the problem.  also the GPU i have isn't showing up in the device manager, just wanted to add that.

someone please help me, i don't have many options.

[edit] - since it seems to me like my GPU is dead, i've looked around for a new one, found another 1050 ti that would work, i just wanted to make sure if i have to get a new one or not.

Comment: "my computer runs fine but the resolution is all messed up and i can't play any of my games now" - This does not properly describe a problem, by providing enough detail, to answer your question.  Please provide a screenshot of your device manage, indicating your GPU, is NOT detected.  You should also provide the relevant information from dxdiag as a screenshot.  Please indicate which Nvidia drivers you have installed exactly.

Comment: basically, my computer has a normal resolution of 1920 x 1080 but now i can't make it go above 1280 x 1024.  not to mention, in the device manager, instead of showing my Nvidia card, it only shows up as having "Microsoft basic display adapter" (the one built into the mobo)

Comment: You need to improve the quality of your question, provide the information required to answer your question, by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things I suggest you try:

- Make sure you haven't missed any relevant setting in the machines BIOS with regard to what the default GPU should be etc - in case you for instance have an inboard Intel Graphics Adapter.
- Since you are questioning your DVI cable try connecting 'anything' to a HDMI port on the card - HDMI to HDMI of course.
- Also you can try and delete the drivers for the card completely using DDU (Display driver Uninstall) from within Windows Safe Mode.
- Since what you are describing could indicate that the card may be faulty, can you try the card in another machine?

DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) can be DLed from:

https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

Then boot into Normal Windows and either install the driver you DL or let  Windows Update handle it for you. I'd go for the first option.

If the card behaves as if completely dead you should get some indication when you try to install the drivers for it. If not then you could use some information utility, Speccy, MSI Afterburner to name a couple to see what they have to say about the card.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for DDU, display drivers for the GPU, should be downloaded directly from Nvidia.